# How to duplicate a Windows 10 Start Menu icon

Tags: windows-10

I don't know what is called, but this is what I meant:

[image]

I need to duplicate an icon here (so that for e.g., I can give a different profile to my Chrome browser on command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a shortcut on your desktop via the `right-click > New > Shortcut` method with the appropriate Chrome options:

[image: New Shortcut]

Once that's done, simply right-click the shortcut and choose `Pin to Start`:

[image: Pin to Start]